# how to reverse a regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, reverse

My regex is something like below

```
    text = 'id 5 result pass
            id 4 result fail
            id 3 result fail
            id 2 result fail
            id 1 result pass'

    for i in re.finditer('id (.+?) result (.+)', text): 
         id = i.group(1)
         result = i.group(2)
         print 'id' 
         print 'result'
```

The output is OK. But how do I reverse it to get the results in the other order where id will start from 1 with the pass or fail result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way is (which will be faster than using a `lambda` in the sorted):

```
sorted(re.finditer(...,text),key=attrgetter('group'),reverse=True):
```

Or you could turn the iterator into a list and reverse it:

```
for i in reversed(list(re.finditer('id (.+?) result (.+)', text))):
```

Comment: This pattern is particularly appropriate when using finditer to discover changes to the text.  Hmm. I'd better elaborate in a separate answer

Comment: Your first example don't work (`TypeError` thrown using Python 3, incorrect results using Python 2). To make it workable, one should use [`methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) instead or [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) (since [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) is a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) method rather than property): `for i in sorted(re.finditer('id (.+?) result (.+)', text), key=methodcaller('group', 1)): ...`

Answer (score 4):

Assign the finditer call to a list and reverse it.

```
matches = list(re.finditer(...))
matches.reverse()

for i in matches:
   # etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by the value of the `id`. This will also work ok if the records are originally in a random order.

```
for i in sorted(re.finditer('id (.+?) result (.+)', text), key=lambda m:int(m.group(1))):
```

In the example given, the sort has O(n) complexity, since timsort detects the input as a single "run"

Answer (score 1):

When using finditer to *change* text we want to discover the changes first, and then make the changes in reverse order.  Something like this:

```
# Pass 1: Find all replacements without changing the text.
replacements = []
for mo in pattern.finditer(text):
    # This may be arbitrarily complicated...
    << compute old, new text based on mo >>
    replacements.append((old, new),)

# Pass 2: Safely make all replacements by making them in reverse order.
for old, new in reversed(replacements):
    text = text.replace(old, new)
```